# Accidentally created a file called "--help". How to remove it?

Tags: delete

I accidentally redirected the output of a command to `--help` rather than passing it as a parameter. How do I escape the dashes to I can remove the file? This is on a headless server, so I'll need to do it from the command line.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this:

```
rm -- --help
```

Comment: Also, while many applications accept a `--` or `-` flag/option to prevent all subsequent arguments from being interpreted as flags/options, in the event that you had to operate on a file called `--help` (or similar) with a command that did not have a `--` or `-` flag/option with that meaning, you could use `COMMAND ./--help` (where `COMMAND` is replaced with the actual name of the command, of course, and `--help` is replaced with the actual name of the file that starts with `--` or `-`).

Comment: Hmm..I never knew that `--` prevented prevented arguments from being interpreted any further.

Comment: @Eliah: Nice point! I'll remember that the next time I make the same mistake :P

Comment: One additional hint: When you're unsure if you're removing the correct file, add the `-i` parameter and you'll be asked for confirmation before a file is being deleted.